# wake up app by region monitoring or signifiacant location change and start location services

Tags: ios, ios7, core-location

My Question is regarding `Location Background Services`.

I have a situation where i need my app to continuously run in background and provide location updates. Even if app is `quit` by user/OS, i need the `region monitor` or `significant location change` to start my app and then switch to `location background service` to provide continuous updates.

Is this functionality achievable on iOS?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

With iOS you can set background modes for location updates in Info.plist file by just adding a key named "Required background modes" its an array and set its item 0 to "App registers for location updates", this will make your app to continues location updates even if app is in background. But for quit option apple doesn't provide any such facility you can read apple's documentation for this.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4

They wrote: "A suspended app does not execute any code and therefore cannot process notifications related to orientation changes, time changes, preferences changes, and many others that would affect the app’s appearance or state."

Which means once we quit our app it is in suspended mode and thus can not monitor for location updates once its suspended.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as per Apple Docs:

Note: If your app is terminated either by a user or by the system, the system doesn’t automatically restart your app when new location updates arrive. A user must explicitly relaunch your app before the delivery of location updates resumes. `The only way to have your app relaunched automatically is to use region monitoring or the significant-change location service.`

Comment: I can start the app even if its stopped by User or iOS itself but is can the background location service restarted in background after the app is awake?

Comment: Well if you can start the app if it is quit by user/iOS you can start the location updates by calling
    [locationMgr startUpdatingLocation];

mehtod in application delegates's applicationDidBecomeActive delegate method like below: 
    - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application{
        [locationMgr startUpdatingLocation];
}